# How to limit jquery date range?

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Can we limit date range for 15 days ? Search date can't be more than 15 days for date range that is why I want to prevent it. how can I do that ?

```js
$(function() {

  var dateFormat = "DD.MM.YY",
    from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
    }),
    to = $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: 0,
    });


});
```

```css
.selected-range {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="book-holiday">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" />
  <input type="text" id="checkout" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see below answer width maxDate:15 what kind of different are there between them ?

Comment: yes but didn't work it: https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/JJJMbW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `maxDate: 15` in option

```js
$(function() {

  var dateFormat = "DD.MM.YY",
    from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: 15
    }),
    to = $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: 15
    });


});
```

```css
.selected-range {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="book-holiday">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" />
  <input type="text" id="checkout" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much it works I will check answer so I want to ask a question what kind of different are there between endDate: '+15d'  and minDate:15 ?

Comment: I know that Both `maxDate: '+15d'` or `maxDate: 15` work , but there is no `endDate` property in the documentation , check it [Here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) :)